# remove all items except one of each class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that contains some items like that

```
<code>
  <pre>
    <div class="multiSel">
      <span class="KNet" title="KNet">KNet</span>
      <span class="Visa" title="Visa">Visa</span>
      <span class="KNet" title="KNet">KNet</span>
      <span class="Visa" title="Visa">Visa</span>
    </div>
  </pre>
</code>
```

I want keep the first item of each class and remove others

Comment: Use [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not) or [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove)

Comment: `$('.KNet:gt(0), .Visa:gt(0)').remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop through the items and the classes...

```js
var classes = [];
$(".multiSel").find("span").each(function(i){
  var curClass= $(this).attr("class");
  if(jQuery.inArray( curClass, classes )>-1){
    $(this).remove();
  }
  classes[i] = curClass;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code>
  <pre>
    <div class="multiSel">
      <span class="KNet" title="KNet">KNet</span>
      <span class="Visa" title="Visa">Visa</span>
      <span class="KNet" title="KNet">KNet</span>
      <span class="Visa" title="Visa">Visa</span>
    </div>
  </pre>
</code>
```

**UPDATE**
sorry for not reading exactly, what you wanted... 
now it should so what you want....

fill an array with all classes... then look with `inArray` if it already exists.. if not (-1) then remove it... so you just keep the first items

Comment: OP wants to remove all except 1 for ea ch class

Answer (score 1):

Use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector along with [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector.

```js
$('.KNet:not(:first),.Visa:not(:first)').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code>
  <pre>
    <div class="multiSel">
      <span class="KNet" title="KNet">KNet</span>
      <span class="Visa" title="Visa">Visa</span>
      <span class="KNet" title="KNet">KNet</span>
      <span class="Visa" title="Visa">Visa</span>
    </div>
  </pre>
</code>
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :**
If all `span` elements has only single class name then you can do something like this using [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter) method.

```js
//$('.KNet:not(:first),.Visa:not(:first)').remove();

$('.multiSel span').filter(function() {
  return $(this).is(':not(.' + this.className + ':first)')
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code>
  <pre>
    <div class="multiSel">
      <span class="KNet" title="KNet">KNet</span>
      <span class="Visa" title="Visa">Visa</span>
      <span class="KNet" title="KNet">KNet</span>
      <span class="Visa" title="Visa">Visa</span>
    </div>
  </pre>
</code>
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :**
Or much better way using a hash map object which holds the classname as the property.

```js
var hasRef = {};

$('.multiSel span').each(function() {
  if (hasRef[this.className]) $(this).remove();
  else hasRef[this.className] = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code>
  <pre>
    <div class="multiSel">
      <span class="KNet" title="KNet">KNet</span>
      <span class="Visa" title="Visa">Visa</span>
      <span class="KNet" title="KNet">KNet</span>
      <span class="Visa" title="Visa">Visa</span>
    </div>
  </pre>
</code>
```

Comment: thank , but the problem is that I have many classes not only knet and visa it's list of hundred classes